# Session counter not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm probably doing something really stupid but i'm unsure what i'm doing wrong.
I'm making a counter that sees how many times the user has been on the index page in their current session.

The following is in a store_controller.rb

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController

 def increment_counter
   if session[:counter].nil?
     session[:counter] = 0
   end
   session[:counter] += 1
 end  

  def index
    @products = Product.order(:title)
    @counter = increment_counter
  end
end
```

And the following here is in application.html.erb layout view.

```
<%= "You've visited this page #{pluralize(@counter, "time")}" %>
```

Of course with other code but that seems irrelevant for now.

@counter displays a value of 0, and doesn't increment whatsoever.

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Your code worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
    after_action :increment_counter, only: [:index]

    def index
        @products = Product.order(:title)
    end

    private
        def increment_counter
            if session[:counter].nil?
                session[:counter] = 0
            end
            session[:counter] += 1
            @counter = session[:counter]
        end  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can eliminate the usage of instance variable:

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  before_action :increment_counter, only: [:index]

  def index
    @products = Product.order(:title)
  end

  private

  def increment_counter
    if session[:counter].nil?
      session[:counter] = 0 #=> Or use 1
    else
      session[:counter] += 1
    end
  end
end
```

And in `app/views/store/index.html/erb` add:

```
<%= "You have visited #{pluralize(session[:counter], 'time')}" %>
```